# Creating A Column Based On If/Else With A List Of String Values For Each Condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying to encode groups of shapes from the UFO sighting dataset to try and increase model accuracy but I'm not sure how to use a list as the condition for each conversion. Below is the code.

```
def shape_group(val):
      if val == ['changed' | 'changing'| 'unknown' |'unspecified' | 'other']: # Uncertain
         return 1
      else:
          return 0
```

its a reduced version but the idea is there. I originally tried with:

```
 if val == ['changed' , 'changing', 'unknown' ,'unspecified' , 'other']
```

and

```
no_nan_df['shape_group'] = no_nan_df['shape'].apply(shape_type)
```

returns no matches

Thanks!

Comment: try this, ``if val in ['changed' , 'changing', 'unknown' ,'unspecified' , 'other']``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
def shape_group(val):
      if val in ['changed', 'changing', 'unknown' , 'unspecified', 'other']: # Uncertain
         return 1
      return 0
```

This would be really quick. Also there is no need of 'else' in the above case.